# Returning REST 400-Bad Request with additional information

Tags: rest

Hey,
I have a REST based server, and in some cases I want to return a failure code (400 for example), BUT, I wish to add additional URL. 
Something like - "failure, but here's what you can do now.."
Is there any good convention to do so?
Is it even a good idea to return error with additional information?

Thanks,
Udi

Comment: Have you considered using redirects (statuses starting with 3)? If you don't want to do that, maybe the Link header would be close to what you want? http://www.w3.org/wiki/LinkHeader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **always** a good idea to return additional information in an error message. The HTTP spec itself [says so](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4): "Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server SHOULD include an entity containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition. These status codes are applicable to any request method. User agents SHOULD display any included entity to the user."

One thing to watch out for: some versions of Internet Explorer will not show the user your additional error information if it is not a certain number of bytes. Make sure your response entities for error messages are at least 512 bytes to be sure.